# How does that implicit passing of function arguments in Javascript work?

Tags: javascript, callback, parameter-passing

I am originally coming from Java programming language as background. Java is strongly typed and quite explicit (I mean by that, you have to write things out, you can't just omit them). One thing, that will never get in my head is how that implicit parameter passing to javascript works...

as an example:

```
const observer = {
    next: console.log,
    error: console.error,
    test: console.table,
}

observer.next('HI World!')
```

in next, I specify console.log which is a function, but I never say to accept a value, but in Javascript I apparently can just throw anything to functions as suffix and it takes that as an argument to its function.
Thats also how pipelining or currying basically works, it takes the remaining return values as parameters..why is that so?

Secondly, e.g in express, I have a function signature like so:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage');
});
```

I actually get req and res out of my function callback is that right? those are not parameters that I pass to my callback function?

**Edit**: Can someone explain to me again where the `REQ`and `RES` parameters are coming from? How does that construct work? Because I am defining the callback function myself, but instead of passing req and res as parameters to my callback, it seems they get passed from somewhere back to inside my callback function?!?!

Comment: That's three separate concepts. 1. `observer.next` essentially *is* console.log now, so you can call either of the two to get the same result. Whatever arguments you pass to your observer.next call end up passed to console.log, it's that simple. 2. currying doesn't "take the remaining return values". When you have `const f = a => b => a + b;` then both `f(...)` and `f(3)(...)` only look at the first argument. 3. instead of calling a function and passing arguments to it, you're supplying a function that gets called by the library. express passes in its `Request` and `Response` when it calls it.

Comment: Well console is another object that has a `log` method and you just assigned that method (function) to your observer object `next` property and then later on you call that log method which accepts some arguments. Not sure what is confusing here.

Comment: Think of your call to `.next()` in your example as _method reference_ in Java that essentially does the same thing: `APrinter aPrinter = System.out::println;`

Comment: Regarding the express part, yes the callback you provide will be called at some point in app.get method and express will pass those request and response objects which means you can use them inside your callback.

Comment: There is no implicit passing of arguments anywhere. Where the functions are called, the call syntax is very explicit. I think what you're actually missing is that [functions are first-class values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

Answer (score 0):

A function in JavaScript is an object just like any other. This means a function can be passed around, can be assigned to variables, and essentially can be used anywhere a value can be used. This is known as **first-class functions**.

For example, given a simple function like this one:

```
function log(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}
```

These two functions are *conceptually* equivalent:

```
const log1 = log;

// same as

function log1(msg) {
  log(msg);
}
```

As you can see, we can directly assign the function `log` to a variable like `log1`, ,and then we can use `log1` just like we use `log`:

```
log1('foobar');
```

Another usage of first-class functions is to be able to pass them as arguments to other functions. A function that takes a callback like in your Express example is known as a **higher-order function**. The arguments of the callback are provided by the caller of that callback. In your case Express provides the `req` and `res` arguments.

Using callbacks is a form of **inversion of control**. You are passing control of that part of the program to the caller.

Comment: ok so does this mean, that in my app object, there is a "get" method with signature: `get(path, cb){ doSomething(path);... create req and res object ... cb(req,res)` ? so in my get method body, I have the req, and res which I pass to my callback to use them in my callback function that I passed itself to that get method? ;) quite confusing somehow...